# Learning Bash: "command not found" error when putting an 'if' statement inside a 'for' loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, syntax

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting 'command not found' on line 11 when I try and run the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
var="nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm"

for counter in {1..40}
do
        var=$(echo $var | base64)
        if [[$counter -eq 35]]; then
                echo $var
        fi
done
```

Line 11 is:
`if [[$counter -eq 35]]; then`

I've tried various indentations and removing the double brackets on the 'if' statement.
I'm expecting the script to print out the 35th iteration of the 'var' variable.
Thank you.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: add spaces behind `[[` and before `]]`.

Comment: I added a duplicate link that explains `[]` since I can't find one specific to `[[]]`. If someone else know that, please let me know so I can add it to my list.

Comment: for future reference: post the entire error message in your question; in this case ... line 11 is the `done` (in the code you've provided); for the code in the question the complete error message would look something like:  `script.sh: line 7: [[1: command not found`; with the complete error message most of us here at SO are going to know immediately what the issue is

Comment: `[` and `[[` are commands, not part of the syntax, so you need to include a space between them and their arguments.

Comment: Always pay attention to the exact wording of the error message. I'm pretty sure that the message does not just say just _command not found_, but i.e. _bash: **[[1**: command not found_, and the `[[1` in the message tells you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

shellcheck.net did indeed find that I needed to add spaced behind [[ and before ]]

Thank you for your replies.